# Why do the limit of $\frac{d\Psi}{dx}$, $\Psi\frac{d\Psi}{dx}$, and $ x\Psi\frac{d\Psi}{dx} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction

When showing that $\Psi$ stays normalised, we arrive at

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lvert \Psi \rvert^2  dx = \frac{i\hbar}{2m} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \bigg( \Psi^* \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x} \Psi \bigg) dx $$

$$ = \frac{i\hbar}{2m} \Bigg[ \Psi^* \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x}\Psi  \Bigg]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = 0 $$

We claim that this equals $0$ because

$$ \lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \bigg( \Psi^* \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x}\Psi \bigg) = 0 $$

since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \Psi = 0$ and $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} = 0 $,
and *these* because $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lvert \Psi \rvert^2 dx = 1$ is finite. $\ $ *(Griffiths, 1.4)*

This may be pedantic, but it’s not entirely clear to me...

**Question 1.**

Why the $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \Psi$ or $ \frac{d\Psi}{dx} \to 0$.

I can come up with $\Psi$ such that the above ($\Psi \to 0 $) is not technically true in the sense that it is Not true that $\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists x_0 $ such that $ x > x_0 \implies \lvert \Psi(x) - 0 \rvert < \epsilon $.

Consider, for example, a sequence $\{ a_i \}$ whose sum converges to $1$.  Then construct a $\Psi(x)$ which is $0$ everywhere, except for spikes, centred at integers $i$, each of area $a_i$.

Furthermore, if the spikes are made narrower as their area decreases, but not shorter, then $\frac{d\Psi}{dx}$ doesn’t approach $0$ either, but rather, in fact, a monotonically *increasing* series can be found.

**Question 2.**

Even if $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lvert \Psi \rvert^2 = 1 \implies \lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \Psi = 0 $ or $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} = 0$, it seems circular to reason that since the integral is finite (ie, $= 1$), the integral must be constant.

**Question 3.**

When deriving the momentum, we get
$$ p = \frac{d \langle x \rangle}{dt} = \frac{i\hbar}{2m} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \bigg( \Psi^* \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x} \Psi \bigg) dx $$

Evaluating the term

$$ \Bigg[ x\Psi^* \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} - x\frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x}\Psi  \Bigg]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \ \text{as} = 0 $$

Which Griffiths section 1.5 claims "on the ground that $\Psi$ goes to zero at ($\pm$) infinity. " Assuming that both $\Psi \to 0$ and $\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} \to 0$ as $x \to \pm\infty$, it's not clear to me why $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} x\Psi = 0$ as this is "like" $\infty \times 0$.  I tried using L'Hôpital's rule, but didn't get anywhere. And it's not obvious to me why it should.

So why are the limits of these three terms, $\displaystyle \Psi, \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}$, and $\displaystyle x \Psi \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}$ equal to $0$ as $x \to \infty$?  And how do we prove that the integral is finite using that the integral is finite? (Why is it not circular)? Perhaps we could instead argue that the two terms in $ \Psi^* \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x}\Psi$ cancel if they are both real?

Comment: If your wavefunction is normalised, it necessarily diminishes as $x\to\infty$. If not then the integral of its norm squared will diverge. Not only that, we could understand that our wavefunction will necessarily come close to $0$ as we go far and far away in spatial direction, namely the limit of its derivative will diminish near spatial infinity as well. As to your last question, I do not think you need a rigorous proof, it is simply asserting any total derivative term evaluated at infinite boundary should vanish.

Comment: @Rescy_ not true. Simply having $\int_{\Bbb{R}}|\Psi|^2\,dx=1$ does NOT imply $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}\Psi(x)=0$. What we can say is that **if** the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\Psi(x)$ (likewise for $-\infty$) **exists**, then it must be $0$ (for the reason you mentioned; a non-zero limit would produce an infinite integral). YOu might object I’m being pedantic, and ok maybe I am, but Griffiths, an author of a textbook (even if he’s not trying to be overly mathematical) should atleast be honest and mention (even if it’s in just a footnote) that he’s glossing over some assumptions.

Comment: and note I’m obviously not saying that Griffiths needs to do all these details, that would be absurd (given his intended target audience, of which I was once a member), because a proper treatment of these things requires Sobolev spaces and other PDE mumbo jumbo. Just that Griffiths should mention that “given certain extra conditions, the calculation shows such and such…“ So, OP, Griffiths is omitting some extra assumptions, but you should just think of it as a restriction on the types of $\Psi$’s you want to allow.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331976/60644

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/747375 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/438009

Comment: Thanks peek-a-boo, I think in this case “pedantic” means “correct”, which in this case is pretty important because that’s a pretty foundational result and to me, it seems a fairly big assumption.  I keep hearing “no physical wave functions” or ones “we care about”, but to me that sounds like “I don’t want to think about it so I’ll pretend nothing I don’t like happens”.

Comment: Some of these links discuss somewhat contrived bump functions, with a similar idea of centering the terms of a convergent series on integer x values.  I think a less contrived, infinitely differentiable solution would be the superposition of Gaussians:  $\Psi = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2^n(x-n)^2}$, which seems a fairly reasonable solution for a wave equation? Here, neither $\Psi$ nor it's derivative goes to $0$.  $\Psi$ keeps returning to the same height, and the derivative blows up.

I don’t understand the claim that these “do not arise in physics”.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I'm happy to treat these questions separately, or make them separate posts, if that is what you mean by needing more focus.   

I do not understand what you mean by my example is the zero vector of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  If this is the space of square-integrable functions over the real line, are the equivalence classes functions with the same integral?  Since my suggested functions all have finite (normalisable) integrals, I do not understand how this plays the role of a zero vector.

Comment: @FurrierTransform Ah, sorry, yes, it seems I misread. I delete my comment.