# Wave functions and Schwartz spaces (QM)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, mathematics

When working with the wave function of a particle ($\Psi(\vec{r}, t)$), my professor always makes the assumption that not only does said wave function fulfill $lim_{r\to\infty} \Psi = 0$ but in fact he assumes that this function goes to $0$ faster than its derivatives. This gives rise to two questions:

1. Under what circumstances can we consider $\Psi$ to be an element of a Schwartz space? Since it is a rapidly decreasing function, I'm guessing it generally does belong to said space, but to be honest I don't know enough math to back up this statement. I'm more interested, however, in knowing when I can assume $\Psi$ tends to zero faster than its derivatives than in the formal mathematical aspect of the wave function
2. Given that $lim_{x\to\infty} \Psi(x,t) = 0$, then does this mean that the first derivative is also $0$ when approaching infinity? That is to say, if $\Psi$ tends to $0$ when approaching infinity, then $\frac{\partial \Psi(x,t)}{\partial x} \to 0$ when $x\to \infty$? Intuitively, since $\Psi$ is getting all flat, the derivative should go to zero as well. The reason I'm asking this is because, after integrating by parts, we often get a term such as $\left. \Psi\cdot \frac{\partial^n \Psi}{\partial x^n}\right |_{-\infty}^{\infty}=0$ and my professor argues this happens because $\Psi$ tends to zero faster than its subsequent derivatives. However, if all of its derivatives approach zero when $r\to \infty$ then I don't understand why he doesn't simply rule the expression out as $0\cdot 0=0$. The only reason why he'd do that is, I presume, because some derivatives actually go to infinity, which doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @TobiasFünke it certainly does help, thanks a lot! This leads me to think that for academic purposes we're always assuming the wave function is $D(P^\infty)$?

Comment: See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/801041/why-do-the-limit-of-fracd-psidx-psi-fracd-psidx-and-x-psi-frac) recent questions, the comments and links therein.

Comment: $D(P^2)$ is all you need to ensure that $\psi$ and $d\psi/dx$ are in $L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a function to go to zero at infinity without "getting all flat". For example, imagine a function which oscillates in such a way that its amplitude goes to zero at infinity, here the derivative of the function is not zero and also might not be infinite, however, if the function itself goes to zero, then the boundary term can be thrown away. Indeed, some wave functions can be a member of Schwartz space (quantum harmonic oscillator), however, this is not necessary (free particle). So requiring that the function go to zero faster than its first derivative is a fail safe mode for always being able to thro away the boundary term.