# Adjoint of the Quantum Momentum Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, momentum, mathematical-physics

I'm studying quantum mechanics and I have a question about the momentum operator. We have that the momentum operator is given by

\begin{equation*}
p = -i\hbar\nabla
\end{equation*}

and so its adjoint is given by

\begin{equation*}
p^{\dagger} = i\hbar\nabla^{\dagger}.
\end{equation*}

The momentum operator is also self-adjoint, so

\begin{equation*}
-i\hbar\nabla = i\hbar\nabla^{\dagger} \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \nabla^{\dagger} = -\nabla 
\end{equation*}

in some sense. However, I haven't run across any explanation of in *what* sense such a relation might hold, or if I'm just completely incorrect. I appreciate any guidance on this!

*Edit*: My thought process is to examine $\nabla$ in a weak sense in Hilbert space, keeping in mind the boundary conditions imposed on wave functions, but I haven't made any useful conclusions.

*Edit:* The domain on which I mean the momentum operator to act is the set of quantum states.

Comment: If you want to speak about self-adjointness, you need to specify domains, to start with... For example, on the Schwartz space $\mathscr S \subsetneq L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ the three momentum operators $P_k$ with $k=1,2,3$ (or $x,y,z$) are symmetric, but not self-adjoint; however, they are essentially self-adjoint.

Comment: Regarding your edit: No, this is not true. The momentum operator cannot be defined on the whole Hilbert space... A self-adjoint everywhere defined operator is necessarily bounded (Hellinger-Toeplitz); but one can prove that the momentum operator is unbounded.

Comment: @TobiasFünke You're correct of course, and more often than not, I guess the domain is $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$, but the Schwartz space on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a subspace of $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for $1\leq p \leq \infty$.

Comment: No, the domain is not $L^2(\mathbb R)$. And moreover, I don't think that the inclusion you cite in your last comment is correct in general, see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18395/what-functions-or-classes-of-functions-are-l1-but-not-l2).

Comment: Again, you're right, of course--what is the set to which wave functions are supposed to belong? I guess the set of functions with bounded $L^{2}$ norm... I think the inclusion is correct though, but it doesn't mean anything you've said is incorrect

Comment: Let me try to rephrase everything a bit: We work with the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$. A linear operator $A$ is, in general, only defined on a (dense) subspace $D(A) \subset L^2(\mathbb R^3)$. An operator is self-adjoint if $A=A^*$ and $D(A)=D(A^*)$, where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint of $A$. So every function in the domain of $A$ is in $L^2$ automatically, but the converse is not true in general. Yet, for *bounded* operators $A$, we can make use of the [BLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension) theorem and extend $A$ uniquely to $L^2$. Not all operators are bounded.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Yes, that make sense.

Comment: Okay... Perhaps I don't get the question, but again: You should include some discussion about the domains of the operator you are talking about; otherwise notions such as self-adjointness make no sense.

Comment: @TobiasFünke You do get my question, and you answered it thoroughly and precisely. If you had written an answer, I would've chosen it. tschüß! (I also appreciate the Arrested Development reference!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider a vector space $V$ with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$ Given an operator $A:V\rightarrow V$, the adjoint is defined as the unique$^1$ operator satisfying
$$\langle A^\dagger\phi,\psi\rangle:=\langle\phi, A\psi\rangle\tag{1}\label{1} \quad\forall\phi,\psi\in V.$$

In OP's case the vector space is the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with the inner product
$$\langle\phi,\psi\rangle:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\phi^\ast(\vec{r})\psi(\vec{r})d^3\vec{r}\tag{2}\label{2}$$
Let us now rewrite the RHS of \eqref{1} with $A=\nabla$ and see if we can recast it in a form analogous to the RHS.
$$\langle\phi, \nabla\psi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\phi^\ast(\vec{r})\nabla\psi(\vec{r})d^3\vec{r}=\underbrace{\phi^\ast(\vec{r})\psi(\vec{r})d^3\vec{r}\bigg\lvert_{\partial\mathbb{R}^3}}_{=0}-\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}[\nabla\phi^\ast(\vec{r})]\psi(\vec{r})d^3\vec{r}\tag{3}\label{3}:=\langle (-\nabla)\phi\lvert \psi\rangle.$$

Where in the first step we have used intergration by parts together with the *requirement* that the wavefunctions vanish at infinity. Comparing \eqref{1} and \eqref{3}, we conclude that
$$\nabla^\dagger=-\nabla\tag{4}\label{4}$$
in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

---

$^1$ <sub>The situation is more delicate for infinite dimensional spaces, in which we should be interested in the present case as $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is infinite-dimensional and more should be said about the domain of the adjoint operator. In other words, **we're not being rigorous here**. The definition I gave works fine in the finite dimensional case, though.</sub>

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you for your clear explanation! My thought process was correct, I just didn't reach the right answer somehow. The key is that wave functions vanish on the boundary. Somehow, I wasn't assuming that the test function in a weak sense vanished on the boundary, only the wave function.

Comment: The argument that general wave functions vanish at infinity is *not* correct. There are easy counter examples of (equivalence classes of) $L^2$ function which do not vanish at infinity.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Interesting. I suppose that for situations of *physical* interest it's about normalizable wavefunctions. Are we really considering a subspace of $L^2$ for physical applications?

Comment: Yes, for example in 1D, by construction of the domain of the momentum operator, all function in this said domain vanish at infinity, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/438009/is-there-a-function-which-is-square-integrable-and-doesnt-tend-to-zero-at-infin) thread. Regarding the claim from my previous comment, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/331976/normalizable-wavefunction-that-does-not-vanish-at-infinity?noredirect=1&lq=1).